# Calculate the division between total height by base's diameter.

Tags: calculus, optimization

[image]
One silo for grains storage was built in a form of a cylinder (floor and walls) with a hemispherical roof. The silo is design to have a certain volume $V$.
Calculate the division between total height by base's diameter which minimizes the surface area (floor, walls, roof).

Comment: What have you tried so far, what do you think might be the relevant equations to minimize?

Comment: I use the restriction V= π r^2 (h+2/3r), isolate h, then replace on equation of surface area: A= 2π rh + 3π r^2 to have a equation with one incognita. Finally I found A' and equals this to zero, to find de minimum. The process is correct?

Comment: Yes, that process is correct.